# One-liner way to invert boolean output in bash?

Tags: bash, jq

Is there a short and clean one-liner way to invert a boolean in bash ?

I have a piped command as follows that looks at the sealed status of Hashicorp Vault:

`vault status -format json -address="https://127.0.0.1:8200" -tls-skip-verify | jq -r '.sealed'`

The problem is that if Vault is in a unsealed state, the value of `sealed` will be *false*, and hence the output from `jq -r '.sealed'` will be false and this will be interpreted as a boolean false in my config management.

So therefore I need to invert the output from `jq`, i.e `sealed=false => true and sealed=true=>false`.

I would like to do this in a clean manner at the end of the pipe becaue the piped command is being used by a config management system, not by a script.

Comment: So just compare it? What have you tried? `| { read var; if [ "$var" = "sealed=false" ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi }`? Or just replace with `sed`? `not by a script` - every script can be used in a pipe, not sure what exactly do you mean by that.

Comment: How about [`jq -r '.sealed | not'`?](https://jqplay.org/s/Cbik32nocQ)

Comment: @BenjaminW. `-bash: not: command not found` ? Do I need to install something ?

Comment: Not `jq -r '.sealed' | not` but `jq -r '.sealed | not'`

Answer (score 2):

jq supports the boolean operations [and/or/not](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#and/or/not). `not` is a builtin function and needs to be called as a filter:

```
jq -r '.sealed | not'
```

---

Of course, if you like to make simple things more complicated, you can use other tools to do this job for you:

```
jq -r '.sealed' | python -c 'print({"false":"true","true":"false"}[input()])'
```

Or with pure shell/bash:

```
flip() {
  read -r b
  case "$b" in
     true) echo false ;;
    false) echo true  ;;
  esac
}
jq -r '.sealed' | flip
```

Alternatively

```
flip() {
  read -r b;
  if [ "$b" = true ]; then echo false;
  else echo true; fi
}
```